# Javascript scope: Callback function throws "today is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote the following code and didn't want to repeat the function (today) twice so I tried writing it within the callback function afterAdd but it didn't work. Why can't it be detected by the callback function?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var today = $(document).ready( function() {
        var todayDate = new Date();
        todayDate.setMinutes(todayDate.getMinutes() - todayDate.getTimezoneOffset());
        $('input[name="purchase_date"]').val(todayDate.toISOString().slice(0,10));
    });
    $(".addform .repeatable").repeatable({
        addTrigger: ".add",
        deleteTrigger: ".del",
        template: "#form_item",
        afterAdd: today
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: I'll change the title but it was meant to be an example. today is what is "not a function"

Comment: what do you think `today` should be? It's the **result** of calling `$document.ready()`

Comment: `today` in your above code will be `undefined` because you don't return anything from `document.ready`.

Comment: jQuery's [`$()` method](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1) returns a [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery) object, wrapping the results of the selector, so in your case `jQuery(document)`

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() { ... }` is meant to wrap any code that you need to wait until the page loads. It's extremely rare, if *ever*, necessary to set it to a variable.

Comment: @JackBashford -returning anything from document.ready won't make a difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create `today` as a function. Then call `$(document).ready(today)`, and also use `today` in your code as per normal:

```
var today = function() {
  var todayDate = new Date();
  todayDate.setMinutes(todayDate.getMinutes() - todayDate.getTimezoneOffset());
  $('input[name="purchase_date"]').val(todayDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10));
};
$(document).ready(today);
$(".addform .repeatable").repeatable({
  addTrigger: ".add",
  deleteTrigger: ".del",
  template: "#form_item",
  afterAdd: today
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
var today = $(document).ready( function() {
    var todayDate = new Date();
    todayDate.setMinutes(todayDate.getMinutes() - 
    todayDate.getTimezoneOffset());
    $('input[name="purchase_date"]').val(todayDate.toISOString().slice(0,10));
});
```

with

```
var today = function() {
    var todayDate = new Date();
    todayDate.setMinutes(todayDate.getMinutes() - 
    todayDate.getTimezoneOffset());
    $('input[name="purchase_date"]').val(todayDate.toISOString().slice(0,10));
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    today();
});
```

This will create the function 'today' and run it when the document is ready.